# Error parsing JSON data. JSONException: End of input at character

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, parsing

Here is my php code fragment for parsing.

```
$result=mysql_query($qry);

    $Json="{";
    for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)
    $newRow=setJson($i,$row);
    if($i!=$count)
    $Json=$Json.$newRow.",";
    else
    $Json=$Json.$newRow;
    }
    $Json=$Json."}";

    $response["success"]=1;
    $response["count"]=$count;
    $response["rows"]=$Json;

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Function for creating new row

```
function setJson($i,$row)
{
$setRow="\""$i."\":[".$row."]";
return $setRow;
}
```

I have developed this using php.
I am trying to parse MySQL result to the following format. For each row in DB. I need to update it to SQLite DB in my app.

```
    {
    "success":1,
    "error":0,
    "rows":{
            "1":["abc","123"],
            "2":["xxx","909"],
            "3":["bcn","1bc"]
        }
}


{
  "tag": "syncMe",
  "success": 1,
  "error": 0,
  "count": "8",
  "rows": "{
\"1\":[\"Porotta\",\"22\",\"652+2\",\"veg\",\"dinner\"],
\"2\":[\"chicken curry\",\"90\",\"sdaS\",\"veg\",\"dinner\"],
\"3\":[\"Assd\",\"12\",\"looo\",\"veg\",\"dinner\"]}"
}
```

How can i remove the slashes in the JSON String.??

Comment: Missing } at end in JSON is a mistake or you forgot about it?

Comment: @AdamRadomski after for loop i am adding "}" with $Json variable. As $Json=$Json."}";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass your result to one array variable using for loop.

Then use json_encode(array_variable);

it will give proper json format..

Why you need to format yourself manually.

You can try this way .. 
Note: some values i hard coded..

```
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
    $Json[$i]=array("abc","123");
}
$response["success"]=1;
    $response["count"]=3;
    $response["rows"]=$Json;

var_dump( json_encode($response));
```

Comment: that i tried that too but it cant give the format i needed.

Comment: i have added it with my Question..i need to make the row in DB as JSONArrays with corresponding row number with it.

Comment: what is your query..? and the row id ur getting from db..?

Comment: SELECT * from TABLE; i took number of rows and using for loop variable i am adding row id.

Comment: this helped me. so i got idea of editing my function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setJson($i,$row)
{
$itemname=$row["item_name"];
$price=$row["price"];
$contents=$row["contents"];
$type=$row["type_of_item"];
$catagory=$row["catagory"];
//$setRow[]=array("\"".$i."\"" => $row);
$setRow="\"".$i."\":[".$itemname."\",\"".$price."\",\"".$contents."\",\"".$type."\",\"".$catagory."\"]";
return $setRow;
}
```

This function parsed my JSON to my requirement.